# How can I change the startup order of applications in Windows 11

Tags: boot, windows-11

### My Problem:

I use an EQ program on my PC for my mic. This program has integration with another device I have called a Stream Deck.

I've come across an issue where the streamdeck software is not connecting to my EQ software on startup.

The support page for the EQ software offers a fix for this, which is to kill both applications, then restart them, EQ first, then streamdeck. This fixes the issue, but it requires me to repeat this process after each restart.

I'm assuming that the root cause of this issue is that the streamdeck application is starting before the EQ application.

### My Question:

Is there a way I can edit the order of the startup applications in Windows so that the EQ application is launched first?

Note that they don't launch from `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder.

If there's a registry edit I could make, that would be great, but I'm not sure where I would find the correct keys.

Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can only do that by running some script on boot, that will start your EQ, and wait for it to start, and then start other needed applications.

Comment: Where are these apps defined (where do they start from) ? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows *Services* embrace the concept of *dependencies*. For example, the *ActiveX Installer* service will *not* start until *Remote Procedure Call* service is already running. If those apps can be [run as services](https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/), then you could make EQ a dependency for streamdeck.

- Make both apps into Windows NT Services (which should still work in  Windows 11). Use [SrvStart](https://github.com/rozanski/srvstart) (which you might need to build) or [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/download) to make each application a  Service.
- Open *Regedit* and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\<streamdeck service name>`.
- If the value `DependOnService` does not exist, add it as type *REG_MULTI_SZ*.
- Edit `DependOnService` to include the service name for *EQ*.
- Set [`Start` value](https://winreg-kb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sources/system-keys/Services-and-drivers.html) to 2 (automatic), or otherwise as needed, for both Services.

***Caveats:***

- Using a Service requires that that it be started and stopped as a Service.
- The applications used to create a Service are considered "hack tools", since they make changes on a deep system level, not apparent to the user.
- Use care... it is possible to make a system unusable with mistakes in this process. **Make a disk image** so you can roll back if there is an issue!

Comment: This was a brilliant idea. Thanks so much. Works without issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the registry path `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` for the current user or the `HKLM` variant for all users.

I can't verify whether the order of keys matters, and whether the system waits for each application to fully open or just calls them all in bulk regardless of which one finishes first.

Alternatively you can create a task using the Task Scheduler `taskschd.msc` which runs `When you log on` which would call a batch script that starts the applications in the order as you desire.